# Unix/Linux "shutdown": How to prevent wall message and terminal blocking?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shutdown

I'm making a script that adds a layer of functionality on top of the `shutdown` command. It's intended to schedule a shutdown a while into the future, and sends out it's own wall message.

How do I prevent `shutdown` from sending out wall messages? Is there a built in way or a separate command that does a similar job but without the message?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: If you don't get response, ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe use `halt` instead? (or `poweroff`)

Comment: If you ask on unix.stackexchange.com, please specify the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `shutdown` with the `--no-wall` option. From the man pages:

```
--no-wall
  Do not send wall message before halt, power-off, reboot.
```

Alternatively, you can use a custom wall message with `shutdown` - e.g.:

```
shutdown -h +5 "My custom wall message"
```

Comment: There is no such entry in the man page. What system are you on? I'm on CentOS

Comment: This is ubuntu 22.04 with systemd version 249.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm on CentOS 6.

Comment: Not related to the question, but isn't CentOS 6 EOL for a few years? I'd be looking to upgrade ASAP unless you have a good reason not to!

Comment: See: [Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) Lifecycle (EOL)](https://endoflife.software/operating-systems/linux/red-hat-enterprise-linux-rhel)